# Nested foreach reads value letter by letter instead of whole word

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, foreach

I'd like to cerate nested foreach and supply inner foreach with value of outer foreach. Problems is that supplied value is itereated letter by letter instead as a whole word.
Here is the code:
html

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: mysections, as: 'section'}">
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
      <div data-bind="foreach: section ">
        b<span data-bind="text: $root.myconsole($data)"></span>
        <span  data-bind="text: $data.content"></span>
        <br>

      </div>
    </div>
```

js

```
  var vm =new function AppViewModel() {
    self.mysections=ko.observableArray(['sec1', 'sec2','sec3']);    
        self.sec1 = ko.observableArray([{"content":"asdf1"}]);
        self.sec2 = ko.observableArray([{"content":"asdf2"}]);
        self.sec3 = ko.observableArray([{"content":"asdf3"}]);

        self.myconsole = function(data){console.log(data)};
    }
     ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/frjapyre/2/ (look up in console to see that $data is logged letter by letter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicly you need to get the value with key 'sec1', while in your code you are iterating key itself.

Try

```
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: mysections, as: 'section'}">
     <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
     <div data-bind="foreach: $parent[section]">
        b<span data-bind="text: $root.myconsole($data)"></span>
        <span  data-bind="text: $data.content"></span>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```